# How to get only N first instances of char in a String column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column with string value of `"x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x..."`.

We would like to go over all the rows and have only N items (all others should be deleted).

The delimiter is `','`.

X  can have different lengths.

How can I do it?

Comment: Try to use substring Function.

Comment: how?  I don't know where the Nth ',' is.

Comment: Welcome to databases 101, chapter Normalization and Relationships. Please read it, do not store comma delimited data that you work with as a single column. Databases are not glorified notepad.

Comment: Better use nomalization.

Comment: Can't normalize. this is legacy DB.

Comment: Plz elaborate with an example.....

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the MySQL function [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

To get this part, assuming you want the first 10 items:

```
SET @N := 10;
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, ',', @N) FROM your_table;
```

To update your table:

```
UPDATE your_table SET 
    your_column = SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, ',', @N);
```

See [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a69f4/1) or [this one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae8f0/1) that shows items with different length.

Comment: @paqogomez My demo is not the best one, because it doesn't show the variable length requirement. Yours does and so does this [new demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae8f0/1).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) five times! `:P` This might be a hackjob, but there's no other way:

```
LOCATE('bar', 'foobarbar', 5)
```

So your code will be like this:

```
LOCATE(',', 'x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,..', LOCATE(',', 'x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,..', LOCATE(',', 'x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,..', LOCATE(',', 'x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,..', LOCATE(',', 'x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,..')))))
```

This might work?

---

Or you can use this: [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,..', ',', 5)
```

Comment: oh yes, there is a way
SUBSTRING_INDEX